# undefined symbol inflateEnd while using ssh

Tags: rhel

I am getting an error while doing ssh from one Linux server to another.
Both are running on RHEL 6.2.

```
server1$ ssh server2
ssh: symbol lookup error: ssh: undefined symbol: inflateEnd
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: reinstall zlib?

Comment: Did you mess up something by installing or removing files manually under `/usr`?